# C++ function prototypes

Tags: c++, prototype

I have just started learning C++. Can some explain the difference between the following C++ function prototypes?

```
void f(int n);
extern void f(int n);
static void f(int n);
```

Answer (score 11):

The void and extern void versions are the same. They indicate that the function has external linkage (i.e. the definition of the function may be expected to come from some other C or C++ file). Static indicates that the function has internal linkage, and will exist only in the current C++ file.

You almost never see these specifiers applied to functions because 99.9% of the time you want the default `extern` behavior.

You may see the `static` or `extern` storage specifiers on global variables though, which is often done to reduce name conflicts with other files in the same project. This is a holdover from C; if you're using C++ this kind of thing should be done with an anonymous namespace instead of `static`.

Comment: Slight nitpick: the first doesn't *necessarily* indicate external linkage.  It could simply be a forward declaration for a function definition which will appear later in the same translation unit.

Comment: @Charles: If the function exists in the same implementation file, then it will be exported by that same file for other files to use, in which case it still has external linkage. (Though, you are correct that the function itself need not come from another translation unit)

Comment: Right, I should have worded that as "doesn't necessarily indicate the function definition is expected in some other C or C++ file."

Comment: @Charles: Modified slightly. Better?

Comment: @Neil G: I'm confused. I did mention anonymous namespaces.

Answer (score 4):

This is more of a C-language question than a C++ one, but:

```
void f(int n);
```

Declares a function f that takes a single integer parameter.

```
extern void f(int n);
```

Declares a function f that takes a single integer parameter but exists in some other file.  The compiler will trust that you have implemented the function somewhere.  If the linker cannot find it, you will get a linker error.

```
static void f(int n);
```

Declares a function f that takes a single integer parameter.  The static keyword makes this interesting.  If this is in a .cpp file, the function will only be visible to that file.  If it is in a .h file, every .cpp file that includes that header will create its own copy of that function that is only accessible to that implementation file.

Answer (score 3):

The first two are the same thing.  The third one gives `f` internal linkage, meaning that a different source file may use the name `f` to be something different.

The use of `static` as in that third example should not be used.  Instead use an anonymous namespace:

```
namespace { // anonymous
  void f(int n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both answers so far have deprecated the use of static functions. Why? What makes

namespace {
void f(int n);
}

superior to

static void f(int n);

? It's not simpler, it's not easier to understand...

Comment: I think the anonymous namespace is a better solution to indicate internal linkage.  The `static` keyword is already overloaded enough.

Comment: @Charles: Strictly speaking, a function in an anonymous namespace still has external linking: http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/835990-anonymous-namespace-linkage

Comment: @Nemanja: That really doesn't matter though; it's effectively static even if the symbol is exported, because it's backed by a real namespace that's given a generated name. You can't call it from other files, and therefore it might as well be static.

Comment: @Billy: You are pretty much right. The only difference is that external linking affects link speed which becomes noticable on big enough projects.

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous namespace is a more universal and cleaner solution, you can have functions, variables, classes in it. And `static` is way too overloaded, in some contexts meaning internal linkage, in others static lifetime.
There is one disadvantage of anonymous namespace though. Because of external linkage, the exported section of your object/library files will swell with all those long `<unique namespace name>::<function>` names which wouldn't be there is they were static.